# YSlow não funciona no Firefox

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox-extensão

Eu possuo instalado o YSlow 3.1.8 no Firefox 49.0.1 mas qualquer link que clico dentro do YSlow não funciona. Alguém sabe como resolver este problema de forma que consiga navegar por todas funcionalidades do YSlow no Firefox?

O sistema operacional é Windows 7

Obrigado